# Distribution of $aX+bX^2+cX^3$ where $X$ is standard normal

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

I am looking for some distributional characteristic (for example a characteristic function) of a random variable which is defined as
$aX+bX^2+cX^3$, where $X$ is a standard normal variable.
Is there some way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the answer is very not nice (even in the case where a=b=0, c=1).